# forgot "administrator's name'

Tags: administration

I still have the password but I no longer have the name I used to create the administrator's account. As I'm a novice in all this, I'm not sure I can safely go `root` without royally messing things up.

How can I retrieve the name step-by-step?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to list the members of the sudo group using either

```
getent group sudo
```

or

```
 grep ^sudo /etc/group
```

There's no need to "go root" to see this information.